# In an arithmetic sequence series formula, can n be negative?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

In an arithmetic series formula, can the n be negative? I.e., if you're looking for how many terms you need to sum in 2 + 5 + 8 + ... to get to say (for example) greater than 243, what if the quadratic you end up solving gives you a negative number? How would that work and why is it an acceptable answer? You can't have a negative number of terms, so why is it considered an appropriate answer?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's an appropriate answer in this context.

Comment: When would it be an appropriate answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think that when you are solving the quadratic equation you are doing so out of context of the question. You can always get solutions to a quadratic (whether real/complex, positive/negative) but when you get them you must check whether they make sense in the context of what you're doing. Really in your example we don't want to just solve $\frac{n}{2}(2\times2+(n-1)3)=243$ but the *system*:
$$ n\in\mathbb{Z}\;\land n\geq0\;\; \land\; \frac{n}{2}(2\times2+(n-1)3)=243 $$
(Where $\land$ is the logic symbol for 'and', so they must *all* be true). This seems reasonable since, as you say, we haven't defined what we mean by a sequence with negative terms; so $n>0$, clearly it must be an integer and the quadratic comes from the sum.  Now if we solve the quadratic and that gives values of $n$ that aren't positive integers then we don't solve the *system* and thus they are not solutions. If you get two integers solutions, one positive and the other negative, then we only consider the one that satisfies *all* conditions, the positive one.

---

**Further to comment**

You can take the absolute value of the negative solution for $n$ and put it into: 
$$ \frac{n}{2}(2(d-a)+(n-1)d) $$ and that'll give the same sum as the positive value of $n$. So in your example you'd put in $a=12$ and $d=4$ with $n=13$ and the sum would be 204. Which can then be interpreted as a series that starts from $d-a$ and then has common difference $d$.

The $40$ comes from the fact when you work out the values of this new arithmetic progression you get the sequence (up to $n=13$):
$$(-8, -4, 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40)$$
which sums to 204. They have just reversed the series by writing it as a descending sum rather than an ascending one, though clearly they sum to the same thing.

Comment: One of my questions in my worksheet asks: "How many terms of 12 + 16 + 20 + ... will give a sum of 208? This problem leads to a quadratic equation with two integer roots. Give an interpretation of both roots." I solved and got n = 8, and n = -13. Clearly in this context n = -13 does not work, yet the worksheet gives an interpretation of the negative answer as follows: (if n = -13, 40 + 36 + 32 + 28 + 24 + ... + 0 - 4 - 8 = 208). Could you explain this?

Comment: @user164403 I'm not entirely sure where they got that from, apart from just finding another series that happened to work. I was looking into a bit before answering and so I'll add a bit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

$n$ cannot be negative or in fraction because number of terms has to be a whole number and also it should not be negative as it is logical that no. of terms can never go in negative.

Thanks.